# Laravel deployment to azure windows web app using GitHub gives error requires ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am getting the following error when I try to deploy my laravel project to azure windows web app using github.

but it is deploying fine if I use azure tool

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v7.29.0, ..., 7.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
    - league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^7.29 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.29.0, ..., 7.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\tools\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I have tried php --ini

C:\Program Files(x86)\PHP\v7.4\php.ini Scan for additional .ini files in:

and in that file it is enabled

```
extension=fileinfo
```

also here is my composer file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4 || ^8",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.13",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.1|^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.29",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "tcg/voyager": "^1.4",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.3",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5.8|^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "platform-check": false
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "repositories": {
        "hooks": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://larapack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching for 24 hours, I have found the solution. This is related to the php set up while deployment. To setup PHP with necessary extensions you will need to update your .yml file on GitHub repository (.github/workflows folder).

Add a new line to "Setup PHP >> with" step like "extensions: fileinfo"

If you need to enable any other extension, you can add all of the extensions as comma seperated.

Example:

```
- name: Setup PHP
      uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
      with:
        php-version: '7.4'
        extensions: fileinfo, pdo_mysql
```

Please read this documentation: https://github.com/shivammathur/setup-php#heavy_plus_sign-php-extension-support

Comment: thank you. couldn't find a solution from anywhere. its working fine with bitbucket. issue hpnd with github